# Pheonix(MySQL) Database for helloPheonix.repo could not be created

Tags: mysql, elixir

I've configured files to use MySQL as my default database from postgres SQL and its showing following error while creatind database

```
C:\Users\kusuma\.mix\hello_phoenix>mix ecto.create
warning: found quoted keyword "test" but the quotes are not required. Note that keywords are always atoms, eve
n when quoted, and quotes should only be used to introduce keywords with foreign characters in them
  mix.exs:57


19:44:31.427 [error] GenServer #PID<0.196.0> terminating
(Mariaex.Error) tcp connect: econnrefused
(db_connection) lib/db_connection/connection.ex:163: DBConnection.Connection.connect/2
(connection) lib/connection.ex:622: Connection.enter_connect/5
(stdlib) proc_lib.erl:249: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
Last message: nil
State: Mariaex.Protocol
(Mix) The database for HelloPhoenix.Repo couldn't be created: tcp connect: econnrefused
```

THANKS IN ADVANCE

Comment: Seems like it can't connect to your mysql database (connection refused). Is your mysql server responding to a ping from your client. Can you telnet to the 1433 port on that server? Can you connect via `mysql` CLI?

Comment: thanks for answer , installing the server again worked for me :)